# Mac application for batch resizing multiple images into multiple sizes per image, with image width appended to file name

Tags: osx, images, image-processing

As per the title, I need an application for batch resizing images into many different sizes, appending the file width to the title.

These processed files could all be saved into one new folder, called 'processed-files' for instance which would then contain multiple images formatted like so:

```
universal-basic-income-1000.jpg
universal-basic-income-1000.webp
universal-basic-income-1250.jpg
universal-basic-income-1250.webp
universal-basic-income-1500.jpg
universal-basic-income-1500.webp
universal-basic-income-1750.jpg
universal-basic-income-1750.webp
universal-basic-income-2000.jpg
universal-basic-income-2000.webp
universal-basic-income-2250.jpg
universal-basic-income-2250.webp
piano-cat-1000.jpg
piano-cat-1000.webp
piano-cat-1250.jpg
piano-cat-1250.webp
piano-cat-1500.jpg
piano-cat-1500.webp
piano-cat-1750.jpg
piano-cat-1750.webp
piano-cat-2000.jpg
piano-cat-2000.webp
piano-cat-2250.jpg
piano-cat-2250.webp
four-day-working-week-1000.jpg
four-day-working-week-1000.webp
four-day-working-week-1250.jpg
four-day-working-week-1250.webp
four-day-working-week-1500.jpg
four-day-working-week-1500.webp
four-day-working-week-1750.jpg
four-day-working-week-1750.webp
four-day-working-week-2000.jpg
four-day-working-week-2000.webp
four-day-working-week-2250.jpg
four-day-working-week-2250.webp
```

these files would be generated from the following input:

```
universal-basic-income.jpg
piano-cat.jpg
four-day-working-week.jpg
```

As you can see, I would ideally need this support both WEBP and JPEG formats.

Ideally this would not require terminal usage but I am open to using ImageMagick if really necessary